# Encrypting connection to SQL Server at an IP address

Tags: sql-server, ssl, encryption, aes

Is it possible to cause SQL Server (2014 or later) to encrypt connections, if that server isn't on DNS (i.e. accessed via IP address)?  I understand that an SSL certificate can only be tied to a domain name, but that doesn't always prevent its use without the server being at that domain name, such as via an SslStream.

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to do that as long as you don't validate the cert by specifying Trust Server Certificate=False. Validation requires the DNS name. The default is Trust Server Certificate=True and should work..

Comment: Here it sais your certificate name must be the fully qualified domain name https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine